# Flask: stream to jQuery/$.post() from generator with yield

Tags: jquery, json, flask

I would like to stream chunks of data from a generator in flask after I called the function with jQuery $.post():

```
@app.route('/some/function', methods=['POST'])
def calculateSomething():
    def g():        
        # do something here
        yield 'result1'
        # do more ...                
        yield 'result2'     
    return Response(g())
```

I call this function from jQuery:

```
$.post("/some/function", {"some": $data}, function(data) {
    alert(result)
})
```

This only gives me one alert saying 'result1result2' and not two separate alerts for each yield. So the callback function is called after everything was 'yielded'.

How can I properly stream to jQuery with yield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one AJAX request and you handle `alert` when all data will be loaded. **You can't get separate chunks because it is one request**, but can try emulate this:

1. You can try use [`XMLHttpRequest2.progress` event](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#progressevent), [`ProgressEvent.loaded`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-progressevent-loaded) and read data from [`XMLHttpRequest2.response`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-response-attribute), but when this event will be handled really hard question (notably for each browser).
2. You also can try look at [`WebRTC`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) but this there are limitations with browsers support and look like unreasonably difficult for your case.
3. Don't forget about `flash` and etc but it's also look like unreasonably difficult for your case.

If your response quick then you can get all response and separate data on client (for example you can use json with base64 for binary objects or blob if you know blob structure).

If your response long because you get big data and you really need chunks then better make several requests because time for new connection will be less then big chunk loading. In this case better don't use big chunks for AJAX because it can throw `timeout` exceptions.

If your response long because it take much CPU or slow operations then better start background process (like `celery`), return response and after check results with some interval.

If you must get response extremely fast you can try use `web sockets` (in this case you already must send different messages).

So when streaming and chunks will be helpful:

1. You downloading or uploading big file and want control speed in flask application (user quotes, don't use all channel for this operation). But if you use for example `uwsgi` your process or thread will be blocked when this operation processing.
2. You downloading or uploading big file and want stop/restore/verify this operation.

Comment: I guess the way to go is move long running processes in the background, save everything in redis and let the client update continuously. Web sockets or something similar are overkill :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use server-sent events in this case. Check out the sample below:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
        var source=new EventSource("/stream");
        source.onmessage=function(event) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
        };
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Data</h1>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
"""

@app.route('/stream', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stream():
    def event_stream():
        n = 0
        while True:
            yield "data: %s\n\n" % n
            n += 1
            time.sleep(1)
    return Response(event_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Server sent events block your development server. To handle multiple connections look into using Gevent. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/others/#gevent

Comment: This does not work for me. `event_stream` just does its thing and the `onmessage` event handler is never triggered. Unless I stop the flask process in which case immediately after all `onmessage` events fire. This seems to defeat the purpose of streaming since you only get all results after the stream runs to completion. Might as well just fetch everything as one then. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is working perfectly for me [Windows 10, flask 2.2.2, chrome 112 and python 3.10]